# C# stop Word Dictionaryfom String

Tags: c#, stop-words

this is C# program to remove Stop Words And 
i have error in  _delimiters 
any one help me please ?!

how can i repair this error 
and the out put should have

saw cat horse
Google searches Internet
Using extra step

thanks at all

```
static class StopwordTool
    {
        static Dictionary<string, bool> _stops = new Dictionary<string,bool>
    {
        { "a", true },
        { "about", true },
        { "above", true },
        { "across", true },
        { "after", true },
        { "afterwards", true },
        { "again", true },
        { "against", true },
        { "all", true },
        { "almost", true },
        { "alone", true },
        { "along", true },
        { "already", true },
        { "also", true },
        { "although", true },
        { "always", true },
        { "am", true },
        { "among", true },
        { "amongst", true },
        { "amount", true },
        { "an", true },
        { "and", true },
        { "another", true },
        { "any", true },
        { "anyhow", true },
        { "anyone", true },
        { "anything", true },
        { "anyway", true },
        { "anywhere", true },
        { "are", true },
        { "around", true },
        { "as", true },
        { "at", true },
        { "back", true },
        { "be", true },
        { "became", true },
        { "because", true },
        { "become", true },
        { "becomes", true },
        { "becoming", true },
        { "been", true },
        { "before", true },
        { "beforehand", true },
        { "behind", true },
        { "being", true },
        { "below", true },
        { "beside", true },
        { "besides", true },
        { "between", true },
        { "beyond", true },
        { "bill", true },
        { "both", true },
        { "bottom", true },
        { "but", true },
        { "by", true },
        { "call", true },
        { "can", true },
        { "cannot", true },
        { "cant", true },
        { "co", true },
        { "computer", true },
        { "con", true },
        { "could", true },
        { "couldnt", true },
        { "cry", true },
        { "de", true },
        { "describe", true },
        { "detail", true },
        { "do", true },
        { "done", true },
        { "down", true },
        { "due", true },
        { "during", true },
        { "each", true },
        { "eg", true },
        { "eight", true },
        { "either", true },
        { "eleven", true },
        { "else", true },
        { "elsewhere", true },
        { "empty", true },
        { "enough", true },
        { "etc", true },
        { "even", true },
        { "ever", true },
        { "every", true },
        { "everyone", true },
        { "everything", true },
        { "everywhere", true },
        { "except", true },
        { "few", true },
        { "fifteen", true },
        { "fify", true },
        { "fill", true },
        { "find", true },
        { "fire", true },
        { "first", true },
        { "five", true },
        { "for", true },
        { "former", true },
        { "formerly", true },
        { "forty", true },
        { "found", true },
        { "four", true },
        { "from", true },
        { "front", true },
        { "full", true },
        { "further", true },
        { "get", true },
        { "give", true },
        { "go", true },
        { "had", true },
        { "has", true },
        { "have", true },
        { "he", true },
        { "hence", true },
        { "her", true },
        { "here", true },
        { "hereafter", true },
        { "hereby", true },
        { "herein", true },
        { "hereupon", true },
        { "hers", true },
        { "herself", true },
        { "him", true },
        { "himself", true },
        { "his", true },
        { "how", true },
        { "however", true },
        { "hundred", true },
        { "i", true },
        { "ie", true },
        { "if", true },
        { "in", true },
        { "inc", true },
        { "indeed", true },
        { "interest", true },
        { "into", true },
        { "is", true },
        { "it", true },
        { "its", true },
        { "itself", true },
        { "keep", true },
        { "last", true },
        { "latter", true },
        { "latterly", true },
        { "least", true },
        { "less", true },
        { "ltd", true },
        { "made", true },
        { "many", true },
        { "may", true },
        { "me", true },
        { "meanwhile", true },
        { "might", true },
        { "mill", true },
        { "mine", true },
        { "more", true },
        { "moreover", true },
        { "most", true },
        { "mostly", true },
        { "move", true },
        { "much", true },
        { "must", true },
        { "my", true },
        { "myself", true },
        { "name", true },
        { "namely", true },
        { "neither", true },
        { "never", true },
        { "nevertheless", true },
        { "next", true },
        { "nine", true },
        { "no", true },
        { "nobody", true },
        { "none", true },
        { "nor", true },
        { "not", true },
        { "nothing", true },
        { "now", true },
        { "nowhere", true },
        { "of", true },
        { "off", true },
        { "often", true },
        { "on", true },
        { "once", true },
        { "one", true },
        { "only", true },
        { "onto", true },
        { "or", true },
        { "other", true },
        { "others", true },
        { "otherwise", true },
        { "our", true },
        { "ours", true },
        { "ourselves", true },
        { "out", true },
        { "over", true },
        { "own", true },
        { "part", true },
        { "per", true },
        { "perhaps", true },
        { "please", true },
        { "put", true },
        { "rather", true },
        { "re", true },
        { "same", true },
        { "see", true },
        { "seem", true },
        { "seemed", true },
        { "seeming", true },
        { "seems", true },
        { "serious", true },
        { "several", true },
        { "she", true },
        { "should", true },
        { "show", true },
        { "side", true },
        { "since", true },
        { "sincere", true },
        { "six", true },
        { "sixty", true },
        { "so", true },
        { "some", true },
        { "somehow", true },
        { "someone", true },
        { "something", true },
        { "sometime", true },
        { "sometimes", true },
        { "somewhere", true },
        { "still", true },
        { "such", true },
        { "system", true },
        { "take", true },
        { "ten", true },
        { "than", true },
        { "that", true },
        { "the", true },
        { "their", true },
        { "them", true },
        { "themselves", true },
        { "then", true },
        { "thence", true },
        { "there", true },
        { "thereafter", true },
        { "thereby", true },
        { "therefore", true },
        { "therein", true },
        { "thereupon", true },
        { "these", true },
        { "they", true },
        { "thick", true },
        { "thin", true },
        { "third", true },
        { "this", true },
        { "those", true },
        { "though", true },
        { "three", true },
        { "through", true },
        { "throughout", true },
        { "thru", true },
        { "thus", true },
        { "to", true },
        { "together", true },
        { "too", true },
        { "top", true },
        { "toward", true },
        { "towards", true },
        { "twelve", true },
        { "twenty", true },
        { "two", true },
        { "un", true },
        { "under", true },
        { "until", true },
        { "up", true },
        { "upon", true },
        { "us", true },
        { "very", true },
        { "via", true },
        { "was", true },
        { "we", true },
        { "well", true },
        { "were", true },
        { "what", true },
        { "whatever", true },
        { "when", true },
        { "whence", true },
        { "whenever", true },
        { "where", true },
        { "whereafter", true },
        { "whereas", true },
        { "whereby", true },
        { "wherein", true },
        { "whereupon", true },
        { "wherever", true },
        { "whether", true },
        { "which", true },
        { "while", true },
        { "whither", true },
        { "who", true },
        { "whoever", true },
        { "whole", true },
        { "whom", true },
        { "whose", true },
        { "why", true },
        { "will", true },
        { "with", true },
        { "within", true },
        { "without", true },
        { "would", true },
        { "yet", true },
        { "you", true },
        { "your", true },
        { "yours", true },
        { "yourself", true },
        { "yourselves", true }
    };
        public static string RemoveStopwords(string input)
        {
            // 1
            // Split parameter into words
            var words = input.Split(_delimiters,
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            // 2
            // Allocate new dictionary to store found words
            var found = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            // 3
            // Store results in this StringBuilder
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            // 4
            // Loop through all words
            foreach (string currentWord in words)
            {
                // 5
                // Convert to lowercase
                string lowerWord = currentWord.ToLower();
                // 6
                // If this is a usable word, add it
                if (!_stops.ContainsKey(lowerWord) &&
                    !found.ContainsKey(lowerWord))
                {
                    builder.Append(currentWord).Append(' ');
                    found.Add(lowerWord, true);
                }
            }
            // 7
            // Return string with words removed
            return builder.ToString().Trim();
        }
    }
}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(StopwordTool.RemoveStopwords(
                "I saw a cat and a horse"));
            Console.WriteLine(StopwordTool.RemoveStopwords(
                "Google searches the Internet"));
            Console.WriteLine(StopwordTool.RemoveStopwords(
                "Using an extra step"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is _delimiters defined? It's not in the code you pasted.

Comment: in this function public static string RemoveStopwords(string input)
        {
            // 1
            // Split parameter into words
            var words = input.Split(_delimiters,
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: That's where it's used, but it's not defined anywhere.

Comment: You have an error in _delimiters and yet that is the code you did not post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function takes an input and the first step is to split your input string by delimiters, however the variable "_delimiters" is not defined.

The split function ([String.Split Method (Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx#)) takes a char array for valid separators, please see the linked documentation.

So as your sample strings have only spaces as separator, adding something like this to your class should suffice:

```
static Char[] _delimiters = new Char[] {};
```

Comment: it works very well thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Words in *natural languages* (English, Russian, etc.) are *difficult* to pin down. I suggest using *regular expressions* as a first try instead of `string.Split` (please notice punctuation, new lines which should be removed):

```
string input = 
  @"“The Iliad” (Gr: “Ilias”) is an epic poem by the ancient Greek poet Homer, 
     which recounts some of the significant events of the final weeks of the 
     Trojan War and the Greek siege of the city of Troy (which was also known 
     as Ilion, Ilios or Ilium in ancient times)";

string[] words = Regex
    .Matches(input, @"\w+", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Another suggestion is to use `HashSet<string>` as a collection for stop words instead of `Dictionary<string, bool>`:

```
// We want:
//   1. Just words without redundant boolean "true" value
//   2. Case insensive: "The" is a stop word as well as "the"
static HashSet<string> _stops = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    "a", 
    "about", 
     ... 
    "yourselves",
};
```

Finally, you can use *Linq* to filter out stop words, e.g.

```
string textWithoutStopWords = string.Join(" ", words
    .Where(word => !_stops.Contains(word)));

Console.Write(textWithoutStopWords);
```

Output

```
Iliad Gr Ilias epic poem ancient Greek poet...
```